# VS Code python extension recently started complaining about a Path error on Win10

Tags: python, windows, path, visual-studio-code

When I start Visual Studio Code with a **`python`** file I started getting the following error

```
The environment variable 'Path' seems to have 
some paths containing characters (';', '"' or ';;'). 
The existence of such characters are known to have 
caused the Python extension to not load. If the 
extension fails to load please modify your paths to 
remove these characters.
```

I checked my path and I did indeed have a **;;** appearing. I removed it but, I'm still getting the error.

Here is my current path.

```
PATH=C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Lenovo;C:\SWTOOLS\ReadyApps;C:\Program Files\Calibre2\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\IDM Computer Solutions\UltraEdit;C:\Users\Dave\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sophos\Sophos SSL VPN Client\bin;C:\Users\Dave\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\Dave\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\sqlite;C:\Python36\Scripts;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Python36;
```

Comment: Did you raise the issue here ? https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues

Answer (score 12):

Your **local** `PATH` contains the following folder paths in this order:

```
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\
C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\
C:\WINDOWS\system32
C:\WINDOWS
C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL
C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Lenovo
C:\SWTOOLS\ReadyApps
C:\Program Files\Calibre2\
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\
C:\Program Files\IDM Computer Solutions\UltraEdit
C:\Users\Dave\.dnx\bin
C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\
C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Sophos\Sophos SSL VPN Client\bin
C:\Users\Dave\AppData\Local\atom\bin
C:\Users\Dave\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
C:\sqlite
C:\Python36\Scripts
C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin
C:\Python36
```

So in **local** `PATH` there is no folder path included being surrounded by double quotes and there is also no path containing a semicolon nor are there two semicolons.

Folder paths in `PATH` should not end with a backslash. It is possible and Microsoft itself added PowerShell folder path with a trailing backslash by default to **system** `PATH`. But I recommend fixing that in advanced system settings of Windows system control panel.

There should be no semicolon after last folder path of **system** `PATH` and **user** `PATH`. Some not good coded applications or scripts append folder paths to **local** `PATH` with always a semicolon at beginning without checking first if `PATH` ends already with a semicolon. This results in **local** `PATH` containing finally `;;`. The semicolon after `C:\Python36` should be removed for that reason.

And the first four folder paths in **system** `PATH` should be always:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32
%SystemRoot%
%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem
%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
```

This means the **system** `PATH` as shown in environment variables dialog and stored in Windows registry should start always with:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
```

Some not good coded installers insert folder paths before the most important folder path – the Windows system folder. That should be fixed by you, too.

I suppose the issue is caused by `;` after `C:\Python36` with a batch file containing just the command line:

```
set "PATH=%PATH%;C:\Folder Path"
```

Or a batch file contains the command line:

```
set PATH="%PATH%;C:\Folder Path"
```

That command line corrupts the **local** `PATH` environment variable because of changing the semicolon separated list of folder paths into one invalid folder path.

See also:

- [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564)
- [What is the reason for '...' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41461002/3074564)

Answer (score 1):

For me it was just a `\` in the end of the Python path:

```
C:\Users\ME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\
```

The moment I removed the last `\` the warning went off !

Answer (score 1):

I met this question and i don't know how to do:
The environment variable 'Path' seems to have some paths containing the '"' character. The existence of such a character is known to have caused the Python extension to not load. If the extension fails to load please modify your paths to remove this '"' character.

Answer (score 1):

i have faced issue and  just uninstalled all extensions in VS and installed again then working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Comes out I had an empty string "" in the paths.
What solved it for me was, and might not be the case for all.
In terminal

```py
import sys
print(sys.path) # lists all the paths, "returns a list"
```

Next: Find the index position and modify the list by removing the empty string using

```
del sys.path[index] #(for me del sys.path[0])
```

restart VSCode that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check the INTERPRETER inside Visual Studio with the command CTRL +P and choose the correct PATH if you are in the [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3R7cO.png)CONDA environment choose it

Answer (score 0):

error corrected somehow, just re-install the plugins. It won't show the path error again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).